# Spring Boot Controller differs in behaviour when called from @MvcTest annotated test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-test

I have the following controller in Spring (2.0.5)

```
@RestController
public class FaqController {
    @GetMapping("/faqs")
    public void get(@RequestParam("language") final Locale locale) {
        System.out.println(locale);
    }
}
```

When I execute GET request via Postman/cURL using url: `http://localhost:8080/faqs?language`, the controller method is called and the `locale` is `null`.

When I execute the same url with @MvcTest annotated JUnit test which looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
public class FaqControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/faqs?language"));
    }
}
```

then the method is **not** called, instead `org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException` is thrown with the message: *Required Locale parameter 'language' is not present*.

Why is that difference? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to be null? If it's not needed then either remove it or set it to not required.

```
@RestController
public class FaqController {

   @GetMapping("/faqs")
   public void get(@RequestParam( value = "language", required = false ) final Locale locale) {
       System.out.println(locale);
   }
}
```

Comment: I prefer the exception over the null. But anyway, I more interested to know, why is this inconsistency in handling this type of request parameters.

Comment: Yeah pretty strange, I'm surprised you are not getting an exception when you hit your endpoint with a null Local. The default should be required = true.

Comment: I do get an exception, but only when the endpoint is hit by the test case. When hit by Postman/cURL, I get the null.

Comment: Yeah you should be also getting the exception when you hit it with Postman because the default is for a requestParam to be required unless it is explicitly set required = false.